# jQuery not getting recent state of checkbox

Tags: jquery, html

I have 6 check boxes in my page and a Submit button. I want to retain the state of the check box after reload. Submit button reloads my page. I have the following.

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">   </script>
    <script src="../js/cookie.jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
     $("input.box").each(function() {
     var mycookie = $.cookie($(this).attr('name'));
     if (mycookie) {
     $(this).prop('checked', mycookie);
     }
    });
    $("input.box").change(function() {
    $.cookie($(this).attr("name"), $(this).prop('checked'), {
    path: '/',
    expires: 365
    });
  });
 });
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <input class="box" type="checkbox" name="1" value = " One ">  One<br/>
  <input class="box" type="checkbox" name="2" value = " Two ">  Two<br/>
  <input class="box" type="checkbox" name="3" value = " Three "> Three<br/>
  <input class="box" type="checkbox" name="4" value = " Four "> Four<br/>
  <input class="box" type="checkbox" name="5" value = " Five "> Five<br/>
  <input class="box" type="checkbox" name="6" value = " Six "> Six<br/>
  <input type="Submit" value = " Submit " onClick = " javascript:window.location.reload(); ">
 </body>
</html>
```

I cleared my cache and ran this. I got the exact output for the 1st time. From second time, the unchecked values are not saved, but the checked values are saved. Can some one help me out?

Comment: Tried checking and then unchecking ?

Comment: Try another browser? If you use Firefox, it is known for having this issue with forms.

Comment: @Florian F: yes I have tried that also.@SwitchingBrains brains: using chrome.

Comment: @AnushaHoney No idea then, providing a jsfiddle might help people give an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input.box").each(function () {
        var mycookie = $.cookie(this.name);
        if (mycookie) {
            $(this).prop('checked', true);
        }
    });
    $("input.box").change(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            $.cookie(this.name, true, {
                path: '/',
                expires: 365
            });
        } else {
            $.removeCookie(this.name, {
                path: '/'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/36Q6k/)

Why your code is not working?
cookie stores value as a string so when you uncheck the value `checked` will be false(boolean) which will be stored as `'false`(string), which when used to set the value will be considered to be true because the string `false` is a truthy value

The proposed solution is to remove the cookie if the checkbox is unchecked.

Comment: Fiddle not working!!! First, I selected all values, clicked on Submit. Again, I deselected an option and Submit, all the options are seleccted!!

Answer (score 0):

This is because cookie data is always a string, in your case `"true"` or `"false"`.

And when you write `$(this).prop('checked', mycookie);` you pass to `prop` method a string, which is converted to `Boolean` type as `true`.

To fix this you may write:

```
var isChecked = (mycookie === 'true');
$(this).prop('checked', isChecked);
```

instead of:

```
if (mycookie) {
  $(this).prop('checked', mycookie);
}
```